# Django 1.5.1 'ImportError: No module named urls' when running tests

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-testing

I've started project with Django 1.5 I've the following urls, views, and tests of the profile app.

When I browse `localhost:8000/profiles` it works just fine 
[image: runserver]

but when I run test for profile app `./manage.py test profile` it fails with the following exception

```
  File "<stdlib>/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in RegexURLResolver.urlconf_module
    self = <RegexURLResolver 'yoda.urls' (None:None) ^/>
    340     return self._urlconf_module
    341 except AttributeError:
--> 342     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    343     return self._urlconf_module
    344
  File "<stdlib>/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    name = 'yoda.urls'
    package = None
     32             break
     33         level += 1
     34     name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
---> 35 __import__(name)
     36 return sys.modules[name]
ImportError: No module named urls
```

#### main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'', include('profile.urls', namespace='profile')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

#### profiles app urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url


urlpatterns = patterns('profile.views',
    url(r'^u/(?P<username>[\-_\.\w\d]+)/$', view='profile_detail', name='detail'),
    url(r'^profiles/$', view='profile_list', name='list'),
)
```

#### profile.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from profile import signals
from profile.models import User


@login_required
def profile_list(request, template='profiles/profile_list.html'):
    """ Profiles list """
    return render(request, template, {'profiles': []})


@login_required
def profile_detail(request, username, template='profiles/profile_detail.html'):
    """ Profile details """
    return render(request, template)


# Connect signals and senders
post_save.connect(signals.user_created, sender=User)
```

#### profile.tests

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TestCase

from profile.tests.factories import UserFactory


class UrlsTest(TestCase):
    """ Testing urls for category application """
    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory.build()


    def get(self, url, follow=False):
        return self.client.get(url, follow=follow)


    def test_list_profiles(self):
        """ Page with the list of profiles """
        self.client.login(username=self.user.username, password='pass')
        print(reverse('profile:list'))
        res = self.get(reverse('profile:list'))
        self.assertTrue(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed('profile/profile_list.html')
```

#### settings

```
import os
import sys

here = lambda * x: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), *x))

PROJECT_NAME = 'yoda'
PROJECT_ROOT = here('../..')

root = lambda * x: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(PROJECT_ROOT), *x))

sys.path.insert(0, root('yoda'))
sys.path.insert(0, PROJECT_ROOT)
sys.path.insert(0, root('apps'))
...
ROOT_URLCONF = 'yoda.urls'
```

What may cause problems like this? In the project with pretty same config and on Django 1.4.5 it works fine.

### Debugging Django internals

Tried to debug Django `django.core.urlresolvers:263`. When `ROOT_URLCONF='yoda.urls'` it fails with the errors show above but I tried `yoda.yoda.urls` and it worked. I'm confused about this problem, still trying to fix.

```
ipdb> __import__('yoda.yoda.urls')
<module 'yoda' from '/Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/yoda/yoda/__init__.pyc'>
```

### Small update

When it receives ROOT_URLCONF from settings we have the following error

```
> /Users/sultan/.virtualenvs/yoda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py(351)url_patterns()
    350     def url_patterns(self):
--> 351         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    352         try:

ipdb> l
    346             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    347             return self._urlconf_module
    348
    349     @property
    350     def url_patterns(self):
--> 351         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    352         try:
    353             iter(patterns)
    354         except TypeError:
    355             raise ImproperlyConfigured("The included urlconf %s doesn't have any patterns in it" % self.urlconf_name)
    356         return patterns

ipdb> self.urlconf_module
*** ImportError: No module named urls
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you created the `urls.py` file outside of app named yoda, then set the

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
```

if you created `urls.py` in a module then set

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'modulename.urls'
```

Try with this

Comment: First one worked though `urls` in `project_name/project_name/` folder here is screenshot http://i1125.photobucket.com/albums/l589/imanhodjaev/ScreenShot2013-04-02at45245PM_zps5e1e7c9e.png