# django "Exception Value: No module named urls" for admin site

Tags: python, django

I am django newbie , trying to follow a tutorial. When I am trying to access  django administration site

```
        http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
```

it giving the error "Exception Value: No module named urls" for the below code

```
    #uls.py
    from django.conf.urls import *
    from mysite.views import *
    # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

    # from django.contrib import admin
    # admin.autodiscover()
    #TODO ADD LIST OF URL
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^home\/?$',get_homepage),
        (r'^admin\/?$',include('django.contrib.admin.urls')),
    )
```

I have tried multiple solution aviable on stackover flow @last publishing the issue get it resolved

```
    #settings.py
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
    # Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
        '/home/abuzzar/djcode/mysite/mysite/template',
        # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or                 "C:/www/django/templates".
            # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
            # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
        )

        INSTALLED_APPS = (
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            #'django.contrib.sessions',
            #'django.contrib.sites',
            #'django.contrib.messages',
            #'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'mysite.jobpost',
            'django.contrib.admin',
            # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
            # 'django.contrib.admin',
            # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
            # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
        )
```

error : http://pastebin.com/RMvzPd61

i tried the solution : [Django 1.5.1 'ImportError: No module named urls' when running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758494/django-1-5-1-importerror-no-module-named-urls-when-running-tests) but did not worked.

Comment: I have *no* idea where you must have found that tutorial, as it must be over five years old. Please actually follow the tutorial on the Django site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [include admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf), use this:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Or, to fix your issue, add `site` between `admin` and `urls`

```
(r'^admin\/?$',include('django.contrib.admin.site.urls'))
```

On a general note, I would revisit the URL pattern. `^admin\/?$` should not have the `$` at the end since you are including another url conf.

Also, `^admin/` should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure not to leave your /admin URL named /admin. I would change it. Otherwise someone can try to brute-force your login or look for holes in your backend. :)

Answer (score 0):

karthikr's answer is the first thing to check.  Also make sure your project folder is included in sys.path.  I'm trying this while using a development environment (Aptana), and have had to change the workspace folder name to avoid command-line issues (the default workspace folder generated by Aptana is chock-full of spaces: 'Aptana Studio 3 Workspace'). Thus the framework was looking in a folder that didn't exist.

A dumb oversight, to be sure, but if you're as new at this as I am it's at least worth looking at.